# Keep track of class instances pointing to updated list

Tags: python, selenium, oop, design-patterns

I am new to stackoverflow and to OOP as well,

The problem: I have a class `TrackList` which is supposed to keep track of the instances of `Element`. `Element` is a class which uses webdriver to find an item of a list based on the index. The list has one item list[0].

```
class TrackList():
  def __init__(self):
    self.instance_list = {}

  def element_instance(self, index):
    if index not in self.instance_list:
      self.instance_list[index] = Element(index)
    return self.instance_list[index]

class Element():
  def __init__(self, index):
    self.index = index

  def _web_driver_search(self):
    #find a node based on the index provided i.e.
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//li[text()="{self.index}"]')
    print("new element found")

  ...
```

Now let's assume that the list gets updated, so the object which were in list[0] = list[1] and a new object becomes list[0]. Unfortunately the current implementation will still return me the old object since instance_list[0] exists. How can I achieve that instance_list[0] points to the new object and instance_list[1] to the old one? Am I missing something or the design pattern is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`instance_list = {}` creates an empty dict (dictionary/map), not a list, so it would be clearer to call it a `instance_dict` if that's what you intended.

It sounds like you want to use a `stack` instead, but I can't say for certain without knowing how the web driver list acts.

If the meaning of index changes when the web driver adds another element, then don't store the index, just get the element from an `array` via an index.  Again, i depends what the web driver does and you need to mimic that behaviour.